# How to run a shell script in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, bash, shell, jupyter-notebook

So I have this shell script that runs a program that I'll be using in **Jupyter**, but is bash-oriented, and I tried using the **subprocess** module,and I get the `error: OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`. However, the script is in my directory with the ipynb file, so I should have permission.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./Heasoft.sh'])
```

That's literally all I have; it works in the terminal but not in the Notebook. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try like `subprocess.call('./Heasoft.sh', shell=True)`

Comment: I did that, and it ran! But I got an output of a number, is that normal?

Comment: it's better you put expected output from the script and put some code to reproduce the error. then it's easy anyone to help you out. Also do your script file have enough permissions? do `chmod u+x Heasoft.sh`

Answer (score 7):

You can also simply run any script by typing in a jupyter notebook cell:

```
%%sh
cat myscript.sh 
./myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

`chmod +x Heasoft.sh` should fix this. If not, add `#!/bin/bash` at top of the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
!pip install Tkinter
%ls
```

See [here](https://www.codingem.com/jupyter-notebook-tricks/) for details.